# Removing a filter from a store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I explicitly add a filter to a `Ext.data.Store` using the `store.filter(string, string)` method.

However, I can not figure out how to remove filters from the store. So the filters always apply even after reloading using `store.load()`. The only workaround I see is to restart the entire web app.

How do I remove a filter from an `Ext.data.Store`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to [`clearFilter()`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)

Answer (score 34):

In addition to Mchi's answer, I want to say that it is possible to remove specific filter ([clearFilter()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter) removes them all).
To do that, instead of using `store.filter('property_to_filter','value')` method, use:

```
store.filters.add('filtersId', new Ext.util.Filter({
  property: 'property_to_filter',
  value: 'value'
}));
store.load();
```

to remove filter use:

```
store.filters.removeAtKey('filtersId');
```

---

#### Update (for > 4.2.0)

In 4.2.0 methods for adding/removing specific filter were added:

```
store.addFilter({
    id: 'filtersId',
    property: 'property_to_filter',
    value: 'value'
});

store.removeFilter('filtersId');
```

For more info check out docs: [Ext.data.Store.addFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-addFilter), [Ext.data.Store.removeFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-removeFilter)

Comment: Thanks for this. But calling `store.filters.removeAtKey()` does not seem to re-load the store (minus the filter). I found that you have to call `store.load()` afterwards to force re-load it. Not a big deal, but if there's a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: @aW-k9IdI'-I0llwlg'I-, nope. Reloading store with `store.load` is, probably, the only option. However you always can extend your store with methods which encapsulate functionality of adding/removing a filter and reloading the store.

Comment: Using store.filters.removeAtKey() directly is not a good idea.  The filter's key indexes are held in store.filters.indexMap and removeAtKey() does not update this dictionary, causing it to incorrectly reflect the filter.store.items and filter.store.keys after the call is made.  This means that adding and removing future filters could cause some nasty side-effects.  Unfortunately, Store.removeFilter() does not appear to work in recent 4.2 versions.  You may try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896163/use-extra-params-in-store-dynamically as an alternative.  It's a lot simpler.

Comment: @CoreyO. The dictionary is not updated at the moment of deletion. But MixedCollection monitors size of collection (`indexGeneration` property). Whenever this collection spots that `indexGeneration` doesn't correspond to actual size of collection it rebuilds indexMap.

Comment: @MolecularMan: The `addFilter` function works on remote stores, but `removeFilter` does not.  In the code for `removeFilter`, they check to see if it's a remote store, and if it is, removing the filter is skipped entirely.  To remedy this, I just used `removeAtKey` and `load` together... seems to work fine, but it feels a bit dirty.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I just found out (browsing the API for something else) that it's even easier. There's a parameter (boolean) which, if true, doesn't reload the data when using remoteFilter...

So here goes :

```
store.clearFilter(true);
store.filter(...);
```

Source: [Store API > clearFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)

I can't believe I struggled for so long with that. In every forum I looked, I saw clearFilter which wasn't useful for remote filtering, and all I had to do was to add "true"...

**Original Post:**

> "You need to `clearFilter()`"

IMO, this is absolutely not satisfying.
When using a server backend to get the data (as many would), with `remoteSort` and `remoteFilter` + paging to manage large result sets, it's even useless.

Calling `clearFilter()` actually reloads the data before reapplying the filter. So 2 ajax requests are sent each time a filter is applied. This has bothered ma for a long time.

All you have to do is actually :

```
store.filters.clear(); // Which is what clearFilter() does just before reloading the data...
store.filter(...);
```