# use extra params in store dynamically

Tags: extjs

I have a form. In the form, I am using a `comboBox` with a `store`.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    id: 'SubContractor',
    name: 'SubContractor',
    fieldLabel: 'Sub Contractors',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    editable: false,
    displayField: 'FirstName',
    store: 'jsonGetSubContractorsList',
    typeAhead: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    typeAheadDelay: 20,
    valueField: 'SubContractID',
    width: 440,
    labelWidth: 229
}
```

In store, in proxy I have static `extraParams`, it's working.

```
proxy: {              
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/admin/contract/subcontractors/jsonsubcontractorslist',
    extraParams: {
        cid : 34
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
},
```

But I don't get, how to send the contract ID to my store dynamically.

Answer (score 22):

```
store.getProxy().extraParams = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
store.load();
```

Comment: Or store.getProxy().extraParams.cid = 34;

Comment: I would even say, store.getProxy().setExtraParam({ ... })

Comment: How would one do a NOT in extraParams, for example foo is NOT 'bar'?

Answer (score 10):

For extjs4, it's rather:

```
store.load({
    params:{
        'foo1': bar1,
        'foo2': bar2
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  .
  . 
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        create: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/create', 
        read: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/list',
        update: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/update',
        destroy: CONTEXT_PATH + '/mvc/odon/delete'
    },
    .
    .
```

Passing the parameter:

```
 var storeDiagnostico= down('gridpanel').getStore();//Ext.create('store.odont.DStore');
        storeDiagnostico.getProxy().setExtraParam("idOdontologia", value);
        storeDiagnostico.load();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys,

I've spent more time to understand all available options and the different. Too many answers about this problem. I've summarized them and hope the answer will help someone.

**When you create a store (Supported in Ext JS 6.x.x, probably in earlier versions):**

```
var store = Ext.create('YourStore', {
    listeners: {
        // Fires before a request is made. op is an Ext.data.Operation object
        beforeload:function(store,op){
            // Set request parameters (without overriding other parameters)
            op.setParams(Ext.apply(op.getParams()||{},{
                par1:'value'
            }));
        },
        ...
```

**When you define a proxy of a store. Supported since Ext JS 4.x.x:**

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'rest/dse',
    extraParams: {
        par1: 'value'
    }
```

**Note: The params are sent for multiple subsequent queries in this case!**

**When you load data explicitly. Supported in all versions of Ext JS (since 3.x.x):**

```
store.load({
    params: { par1: "value" }
});
```

Note: it is not needed to put `par1` inside of ‘’ or “”.

Alternative sub-option, which uses access to proxy and its extraParams option:

```
store.getProxy().extraParams = {
    par1: 'value'
};
store.load();
```

Be careful with this. This parameter is sent for multiple subsequent queries!

**When you create a store. Supported only in Ext JS 3.x version.**

```
var genres1 = new Ext.data.Store({
    baseParams: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    },
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome and FF even this will work:

```
store.proxy.extraParams.foo= 'bar';
```

But in IE8 (had this problem personally)
got to do it the way mentioned by Evan

```
store.proxy.extraParams = {foo: 'bar'};
```

[Check this...](http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/extjs-storeproxyextraparams-is.html)